# Does a Mistress get anything from torturing?

Tags: dungeon-keeper-2

I got Dungeon Keeper 2 on GOG a while ago and have been playing it recently.   Any enemy hero creatures I capture I try and convert to my side by torturing them, and every so often the Mistress comes in and seems to torture them too.

So does the Mistress gain XP towards her level with this?  Or is it just an animation thing?  I keep removing them from the room on the off chance they actually kill the creature before it's converted.

Also, when the Mistress uses the torture chamber herself does she get anything from using the devices?  Or is it just like a Casino and it is 'her' way of 'having fun' when not fighting?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. What a great game series! Loved the first especially. Enjoy :)

Comment: Same for me, it's a great game and a pleasure to play!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 important facts about that [here](http://dungeonkeeper.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Mistress)

**First: They just like a litte bit of pain**

They just like it. Letting them getting tortured a bit makes them happier. Alternatively you can slap them yourself.

**Second: Painloving girls mean brave fighters**

According to the linked page the mistresses' love for pain leads to a higher duty for combat. So she is not scared by any enemy, no matter how low her winning chances may be.

Hope this helps.